# BigQuery, SQL - closest pair of between tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables each containing similar pairs of values but not exact matches.

Table with correct pairs of values is "base_table"
[base_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtuQg.png)

Table with aproximate pairs of values is "table2"

[table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFAGD.png)

I want to link the "order_id" column in "table2" with the correct pair of values in "base_table" to get a final result like the table "result". This table is taking the exact pair of values and joining them with the "order_id" column in the same table.

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biuT4.png)

Any kind of idea is very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For this specific use case, you can use `CROSS JOIN` and specify the fuzzy matching at the `WHERE` clause:

```
select
  order_id, user_id, a2, b2
from
  base_table as bt
cross join
  table_2 as tt 
where 
  (bt.a2 between tt.a - 0.3 and tt.a + 0.3) and
  (bt.b2 between tt.b - 0.3 and tt.b + 0.3)
order by 
  1
```

**Output:**

```
order_id user_id a2     b2
-------- ------- ------ ------
1001     joe     4.359  7.263
1002     tony    6.1883 8.15
1003     nick    7.241  9.1001
1004     mark    9.1    4
1005     frank   4.09   6
```